# PlatformException Error (channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null) with Flutter on using firebase libraries for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, cocoapods, unhandled-exception

I am getting this error in flutter while building for iOS during debug build pointing to Firebase.initializeApp. Not able to understand the reason here.
here is my pubspec.yaml for firebase libraries: (using flutter 2.10.2/ dart 2.16.1)

```
  firebase_core: 1.18.0
  firebase_auth: 3.3.20
  firebase_storage: 10.2.18
  firebase_messaging : 11.4.2
  cloud_firestore: 3.1.18
  firebase_crashlytics: 2.8.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: 4.2.6
```

I am attaching the full error in the debug console as well:
[Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xfdn.png